# Putting tools you use (but can't configure) on resume?

Tags: resume

I'm a software developer. There are a few tools that I know how to use, but can't really configure.

Example: I use Jenkins. I can set up what I need to setup for my project - I know my way around the user interface. But I couldn't set up an entire Jenkins server from scratch to get it to the point where someone could use the user interface.

So could I still put that I can use the tool on my resume? If so, would I put some type of disclaimer?

Comment: Configuring something is just following their instructions. You could just do it https://jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#docker. Usually takes me ~1-2hrs.

Comment: Does the job you're applying for require you to be able to setup a Jenkins server from scratch?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Yes, put it in. Don't put a disclaimer.

Just don't lie in your job description. People can tell the difference between "Used Jenkins to do regression testing" vs. "Installed Jenkins from scratch to set up a CI environment."

Comment: I had the same issue with operating systems. I added in brackets "user-level experience", I think that's a good balance between disclaiming everything and being thorough.

Comment: @Bennet So you know how to use an operating system, but you don't know how to set one up from scratch? It seems pretty clear to me which one you mean if you write "Experience with windows 10".

Comment: I just write: IT skills: Python (advanced), C++ (intermediate), ..., Windows, Linux, Mac (user-level) . I think it fits together nicely, actually, but it's just my $0.02

Comment: @R.Schmitz that might depend on the context: programmer job, yeah, my first assumption would be 'usage', while my first assumption on a techops position would be 'administration', but for a devops position it would not be so clear. Or if the CV has some stints in different areas. The less you fit a normative type, where context gives a clear indication (and that indication is correct for yourself), the more explicit you typically need to be.

Comment: "People can tell the difference between" And if they can't, that's maybe all better for you, or some warning flag, depending on what you wanna do.

Comment: @Bennet I used to do that, adding levels. But it got cumbersome for me and distracting for the panel, so I started leaving it out again.

Comment: It's not just HR and bots that read resumes. As a technical person that (occasionally) interviews dev candidates, I appreciate when resumes break it down by level of familiarity. You don't need to put it in brackets after each thing, you can create different sections each with their own list.

Comment: The flipside of not differentiating is risking the following awkward situation: "I see you have XYZ on your CV, please can you answer this [tricky interview question]", then needing to weazel out of it. There are technologies I used and could pick up again, but won't answer in-depth questions about on the spot. In my opinion, it is better to be up-front in such cases.

Answer (score 65):

Short answer: Put the technology/tool in the resume, and keep its discussion to the interview.

Comment: Exactly. when in doubt, they'll ask. That's the moment to tell what actual experience you got with it (not disclaimer style, keep talking from the perspective of the tasks completed).

Answer (score 20):

Yes. Put it in without a disclaimer.

You’re applying for a software developer position so in most cases, there wouldn’t be any expectation that you know Jenkins from an administration perspective as that is more suited for roles like build/release engineers, devops engineers, etc.

All those roles are sometimes done by a single person in smaller operations so it’s something that you can clear up in the interview if not clear on the job posting.

For your specific case, putting in “Software Developer” plus Jenkins will also communicate the following:

- you are familiar with automated builds
- you are familiar with source control
- high likelihood that you’re familiar with automated tests
- you’re familiar with what happens next when builds break from a Software developer standpoint

Comment: It certainly helps to have end-to-end knowledge of how the technology stack works, but if it’s not part of the job description, there’s no need to advertise the fact that you don’t know it.

Answer (score 16):

Resumes need to get through HR's bots and keyword searches to matter. Throw it on there.

Answer (score 10):

I split the technical experience part of my resume into 3 sections

- Proficient in
- Familiar with
- Tools and Technologies

That way (if someone actually reads it) the reader can at a glance get a feel for how much experience I have with anything listed.

For your case, I'd put Jenkins in the "Familiar with" category.

Comment: But what if I'm proficient in using something but only "familiar with" setting it up? For example, I can use it really well, but can't setup a really nice environment for it?

Comment: @undefined, In that case, I would list both use-cases under their corresponding headings.

Comment: @ArnoldWiersma thus generating a lot of duplicate entries, or needing to specify which aspect of the tool you're familiar or proficient with. I'd rather keep it brief and explain during the interview if needed.

Comment: @undefined I would avoid duplicate entries; this might look like a mistake. Instead, explicitly list what you are referring to. If you list a tool by name I would expect you to be a user of that tool only not an administrator.